# Pivot detect when animation completes

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Is there a way to detect when Pivot animation completes after swipe? I tried the PivotItemLoaded event, but it does not work. I also tried delaying another work for 1 second when SelectedIndex changes but it's not a very good solution.

Comment: I'm always using the SelectionChanged event... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot.selectionchanged(v=vs.105).aspx not sure on how you would actually know when the gesture has finished though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use gesture flick event.like below

**XAML**

```
 <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="OnFlick"/>
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
```

**C# Code**

```
private void OnFlick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
  {
     var vm = DataContext as SelectedCatalogViewModel;
     if (vm != null)
     {
        // User flicked towards left
        if (e.HorizontalVelocity < 0)
        {
           // Load the next image 
           LoadNextPage(null);
        }

        // User flicked towards right
        if (e.HorizontalVelocity > 0)
        {
           // Load the previous image
           LoadPreviousPage();
        }
     }
  }
```

Hope it will help you ....

Comment: I think this is not what I need. This event is fired when user uses the swipe gesture, but I need to call a method when the animation of the pivotitem is completed

Comment: @Kristian Vukusic:there is no method in pivot control for swipe completed.you have to add gesture in you pivot designing code so when you swipe pivot gesture ll also generate...fine if you want to use than you can otherwise as your wish....thanks